# Can not change the default value of <select> useing the react states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, state

i am trying to change the default value of  by useing react state but it just ignore what the state is and take the first value in the list

```
function EditGendr(props) {
  return (
    <div className="EditProfileDropElement">
      <p className="editMetaData">{props.metaData}</p>
      <select
        id={props.id}
        className={props.class}
        defaultValue={props.value}
        onChange={props.handeler}
      >
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this component just renders the  for gender

```
         <EditGendr
              id="gender"
              metaData="Gender"
              value={this.state.gender}
              class="editInput"
              handeler={this.genderHandelChange}
            />
```

this is the state :

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  email: "",
  gender: "",
  dateOfBirth: "",
  country: "",
  displayName: "",
  password: "",
  formNotValid: "",
  formSaved: "",
  formErrors: {
    emailError: "",
    displayNameError: "",
    passwordErorr: ""
  }
};
```

here where i set the value from local server

```
 componentDiMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/me")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          email: response.data.email,
          gender: response.data.gender,
          dateOfBirth: response.data.birthDate,
          displayName: response.data.displayName,
          country: response.data.country
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

[this what i got but this is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCmCD.png)
[this is the correct optio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwrti.png)

Comment: Hey can you please also `upvote` my answer ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `<select>` you have to specify the `value` not the `defaultValue`. So your jsx will look like this:

```html
<select
  id={props.id}
  className={props.class}
  value={props.value}
  onChange={props.handeler}  
>
```